# Error while installing Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento2

I have downloaded the Magento community edition and the sample data. I am using XAMPP and while when I try to install Magento, all the five steps are fine as you can see below

[image]

When I click on the install button, the installation process stops with following error message

```
Module 'Magento_Widget':

Installing schema..  [ERROR] exception 'Zend_Db_Exception'
with message 'Column "code" does not exist in table "widget".'
in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php:967

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\module-widget\Setup\InstallSchema.php(102): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->changeColumn('widget', 'code', 'widget_code', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(798): Magento\Widget\Setup\InstallSchema->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(732): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema') 
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(331): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() 
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

Please somebody help me resolve this issue

Comment: check your folder permission. And retry

Comment: Hi Shine i have checked the folder permissions they all are 777 only.

Comment: Then you should try a new installation it will be better.

Comment: Are you installing magento 2.0?

Comment: Ya i am installing the magent0 2.0 only.

Comment: Make sure you drop the database before you install. php bin/magento setup:uninstall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is ,the database was not clean.so while installing make sure the database is empty and now the installation will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure that you have entered right database name at database details step.
2. Check your database it must be clean. If you have imported the database from your Magento theme then clean it or create empty database. (Note : Database should be empty during Magento installation)